# How to select specific rows twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query some rows and in the resultset I want a subset of these rows twice.

With `UNION ALL` I can achieve this.

Are there other ways?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt. Mostly likely the solution is `UNION ALL` - why do you want another way?

Comment: If using `UNION ALL` works - why do you need *other ways* ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @marc_s maybe they want to learn, or want to avoid multiple physical table operations.

Comment: There is no why applicable to this question unfortunately, that I would be aware of. But certainly other people will exactly know why they want to have alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a join to multiplicate rows, for example on a condition.

With `stackoverflow (foo, bar)` with values ('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4) imagine you want to have one copy of rows always, duplicate records with even bar value and maybe duplicate records for foo starting with 't'. You can join an explicit values clause conditionally:

```
select so.*
  from stackoverflow so
 inner
  join (values (1), (2), (3)) copies(no)
    on copies.no = 1 -- first copy always
    or (copies.no = 2 and so.bar % 2 = 0) -- a copy for even bar records
    or (copies.no = 3 and so.foo like 't%') -- a copy for foo starting with 't'
```

you'll get one row for 1, three rows for 2 (because it's even and starts with t), two rows for 3 (because starts with t) and two rows for 4 (because even).

[dbfiddle.uk live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KKdzAm6l)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have this table:

```
create table my_table(id int, name varchar(10));
insert into my_table values (1, 'Kenny'), (2, 'Eric'), (3, 'Stan'), (4, 'Kyle');
```

Eric is bigger, he needs three rows, so let's make them recursive way:

```
with rec(id, name, copy) as (
  select id, name, 1 from my_table union all
  select id, name, copy + 1 from rec where name = 'Eric' and copy < 3)
select id, name, copy from rec
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QQ_jlFkf)